# Splitting a value in to current date and next date with SQL in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, lead

I want to split the sales data of one day up into that specific day and the next day with SQL. In the first table underneath you can see the data I have and in the second table an example of the data I want to have.

*Table 1: Current situation*

```
|  Date     |   Country   | discount_code    | sales | 
|-----------|-------------|------------------|-------|
|2020-12-03 |   US        | Instagram        | 300   | 
|2020-12-03 |   UK        | Google           | 200   | 
|2020-12-02 |   US        | Instagram        | 500   | 
|2020-12-02 |   UK        | facebook         | 600   |
```

*Table 2: Required situation*

```
|  Date     |   Country   | discount_code    | sales1 | sales2 | 
|-----------|-------------|------------------|--------|--------|
|2020-12-04 |   US        | Instagram        | 0      | 150    |
|2020-12-04 |   UK        | Google           | 0      | 100    |
|2020-12-03 |   US        | Instagram        | 150    | 250    |
|2020-12-03 |   UK        | Google           | 100    | 0      |
|2020-12-03 |   UK        | facebook         | 0      | 300    |
|2020-12-02 |   US        | Instagram        | 250    | 0      |
|2020-12-02 |   UK        | facebook         | 300    | 0      |
```

I tried to solve it myself in the following query:

```
SELECT 
date,
country,
discount_code,
sum(sales/2) AS sales1,
LEAD(sum(sales/2), 1) OVER (ORDER BY date, country, discount_code) AS sales2,
FROM `source`
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY date DESC
```

This code only assigns the `sales2` to be assigned to the row above. However, I want `sales2` to be specific for `date`, `country` and `discount_code`. This would entail that when such a row does not already exist, it is created.

I hope anyone has a solution for this. It would help me enormously.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? `FROM \`source\`` isn't valid T-SQL.  You also have a trailing comma after `sales2` and why are you grouping on column `4`, when it's an aggregate? Also, you shouldn't be grouping on oridinal positions anyway and should be using the column's name/expression.

Comment: Does "This would entail that when such a row does not already exist, it is created." mean you have data for (date, country, code) but no data for (date+1, country, code)? Or no data for (date+1, country)?  What if there is no data that correspond to sales1 or sales2 do you want a record or not?  I would probably generate rows you want (date rate) join (countries) join (coupon codes) then left join with the sales data and do conditional sum(if(date == date, x, 0), sum(if(date == date +1, x, 0).  if is syntax is mysql specific, I think, case is the other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select t.date, t.country, t.discount_code,
  sum(sales1) as sales1, sum(sales2) as sales2
from `project.dataset.source`, 
unnest([struct
  (date, country, discount_code, sales/2 as sales1, 0 as sales2),
  (date + 1, country, discount_code, 0, sales/2)
]) t
group by date, country, discount_code
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This seems like unpivoting and aggregation:

```
select v.date, s.country, s.discount_code,
       sum(v.sales1) as sales1, sum(v.sales2) as sales2
from source s cross apply
     (values (s.date, s.sales / 2, 0),
             (dateadd(day, 1, s.date), 0, s.sales / 2)
     ) v(date, sales1, sales2)
group by v.date, s.country, s.discount_code;
```

In case you are *not* using SQL Server, you can also express this using `union all` and aggregation.  Date functions vary among databases, but something like this:

```
select s.date, s.country, s.discount_code,
       sum(v.sales1) as sales1, sum(v.sales2) as sales2
from ((select date, country, discount_code, sales / 2 as sales1, 0 as sales2
       from source s 
      ) union all
      (select date + interval 1 day, country, discount_code, sales / 2 as sales1, 0 as sales2
       from source s 
      ) 
     ) s
group by s.date, s.country, s.discount_code;
```